# Lotus Notes: Is it possible to create a view that excludes documents in all folders other than Inbox?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus-formula

I am aware that you can exclude certain folders - but you have to name them. I need a view to show only the documents in the inbox, that doesn't need updating everytime we create a new folder.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

:)

Comment: There is @WhichFolders function. But I think it only works in a column.

Comment: I think that even if you find a select formula for such a view, it will not be up to date when a document is moved to another folder... The problem is that the document is not modified when it's moved only the "folders documents collection" are changed. A view will not be flaged as to be updated if doc are not modified. (like the old style trick with @date("today") in text to avoid continual reconstruction of the view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible directly.  There are no formulas that would help you build a select statement to get documents that are only in the Inbox.  However, you could have an agent run on a scheduled basis (maybe every 5-10 minutes) that would update documents and flag them if they are in the inbox.  Your view would then just need to select documents that have that flag set.

**Updated** As umeli pointed out, the flag needs to be unset when documents are moved out of the Inbox.  Here's a modified script:

For example:

```
Dim s as New NotesSession
Dim db as NotesDatabase
Dim view as NotesView
Dim doc as NotesDocument
Dim allEntriesInbox as NotesViewEntryCollection
Dim allEntriesFlagged as NotesViewEntryCollection    

Set s = New NotesSession
Set db = s.CurrentDatabase
Set view = db.GetView("($Inbox)")
Set viewFlagged = db.GetView("IsInInboxView")

Set allEntriesInbox = view.AllEntries
Set allEntriesFlagged = viewFlagged.AllEntries

allEntriesFlagged.StampAll("IsInInbox", "")
allEntriesInbox.StampAll("IsInInbox, "1")
```

Your view (named "IsInInboxView" in this example) should have a selection formula of `IsInInbox = "1"`